# How to recover deleted data in mongodb server

Tags: mongodb

I have an existing React project running. I ran React at localhost and deleted all the data. The data in Mongodb server has been deleted.
How can I recover deleted data from Mongodb server?
Thank You So Much.

Comment: Do you have a backup?

Comment: A delayed secondary might help, but only if it is set up before the "accidental" delete.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.